# Dependency error when installing discord

Tags: linux, kali-linux, package-management, packages, discord

Guys I'm trying to install discord on my Kali Linux, but I'm getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: 
libappindicator1
```

I tried to install with **`apt-get install libappindicator1`** but the error continues does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

**Edit:**

Note when I try to install via apt displays this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libappindicator1
```

What I do know is that I’m missing a link from source.list but I don’t know what the link is and I’m not sure how to add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `libappindicator` has been removed from Kali Rolling [since 2021-01-19](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/libappindicator):

```
[2021-01-19] libappindicator 0.4.92-8 removed from kali-rolling (Kali Repository)
```

To install `discord` use `snap`:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd apparmor
sudo snap install discord
snap connect discord:system-observe
```

[discord on snapcraft.](https://snapcraft.io/discord)

[Installing snap on Kali Linux.](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-kali)

#### Edit

> snapd command not found

You need to edit your sources.list through:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Comment: Is it possible to install without starting every time you reboot?

Comment: When I run `apt-get install snapd` It shows this: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
snapd is already the newest version (2.48.2-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.` but when I run snapd it shows this: `Command 'snapd' not found`

Comment: @Dakota See my edit please.

Comment: @Dakota you install ```snapd``` and execute ```snap``` from terminal.